# How to return the difference between 2 strings using Oracle SQL only

Tags: sql, string, oracle, difference, oracle-fusion-apps

I have 2 strings for example:

- 'Source:Siebel; Name:Mary Jane; Gender:F; Age:24; N;'
- 'Source:Siebel; Name:Marie; Gender:F; Age:24; N;'

The result I need is:

- Name:Mary Jane;
- Name:Marie;

Most likely I need to reverse below code

```
with cte1 as  (
    select 1 id, 'Source:Siebel; Name:Mary Jane; Gender:F; Age:24; N;' str from dual
    union all
    select 2 id, 'Source:Siebel; Name:Marie; Gender:F; Age:24; N;' str from dual
), cte2 as (
    SELECT distinct id, trim(regexp_substr(str, '[^ ]+', 1, level)) str
    FROM cte1 t
    CONNECT BY instr(str, ' ', 1, level - 1) > 0
)
select distinct t1.str
from cte2 t1
join cte2 t2 on (t1.str = t2.str and t1.id != t2.id)
```

from 
[Oracle Function to return similarity between strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31756297/oracle-function-to-return-similarity-between-strings)

as the result was the similarities
[QueryResult] of the 2 strings

[image]

I cannot use the procedure as I need this SQL script to run in Oracle Fusion

Comment: Why is the data in that format to begin with? Even if it comes from some source that only outputs complex strings like that, when you import the data in your database it should first be normalized.

Comment: Hello, I used that sample data because the actual data I'm working with is concatenated values from Interface Table and Base tables of Oracle. And I am comparing from the results of the two to ensure that the data from Interface table was passed to Base table,

Comment: I am not sure I understand. The data either was passed from "interface" to "base tables" or it wasn't; I don't see how "Mary Jane" could have been changed to "Marie" in the process. Copying or transferring data from one place to another can fail in many ways, but altering the content of the data would be exceptionally rare (I think).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this help?

```
SQL> with cte1 as  (
  2   select 1 id, 'Source:Siebel; Name:Mary Jane; Gender:F; Age:24; N;' str from dual
  3   union all
  4   select 2 id, 'Source:Siebel; Name:Marie; Gender:F; Age:24; N;' str from dual
  5   ),
  6  cte2 as
  7    (select id,
  8       column_value lvl,
  9       trim(regexp_substr(str, '[^;]+', 1, column_value)) str
 10     from cte1 cross join
 11       table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 12                           connect by level <= regexp_count(str, ';') +1
 13                          ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 14    )
 15  select a.str, b.str
 16  From cte2 a join cte2 b on a.id < b.id and a.lvl = b.lvl and a.str <> b.str;

STR             STR
--------------- ---------------
Name:Mary Jane  Name:Marie

SQL>
```

Comment: hey! i think this will work. I just need to incorporate this with my whole script

Comment: This won't work if there are more than two rows or strings in OPs example.

Comment: Keyword is "IF". As far as we know, there aren't.

Answer (score 0):

> The result I need is:

```
Name:Mary Jane; 
Name:Marie;
```

You could use `LAG/LEAD` **analytical function** to get your desired output.

Demo with multiple input values, e.g. 'Mary Jane', 'Marie', 'Jane', 'Jones'

```
with t1 as  (
    select 1 id, 'Source:Siebel; Name:Mary Jane; Gender:F; Age:24; N;' str from dual
    union all
    select 2 id, 'Source:Siebel; Name:Marie; Gender:F; Age:24; N;' str from dual
    union all
    select 3 id, 'Source:Siebel; Name:Jane; Gender:F; Age:24; N;' str from dual
    union all
    select 4 id, 'Source:Siebel; Name:Jones; Gender:F; Age:24; N;' str from dual
), t2 as (
SELECT t1.id,
        trim(regexp_substr(t1.str, '[^;]+', 1, lines.column_value)) str
    FROM t1,
      TABLE (CAST (MULTISET
      (SELECT LEVEL FROM dual
              CONNECT BY instr(t1.str, ';', 1, LEVEL) > 0
      ) AS sys.odciNumberList ) ) lines
    ORDER BY id, lines.column_value)
select id, str from(
  select id, 
         str, 
        lag(str) over(partition by str order by str) lag, 
        lead(str) over(partition by str order by str) lead from t2
) where lag is null
  and   lead is null
order by id;

        ID STR
---------- -----------------------
         1 Name:Mary Jane
         2 Name:Marie    
         3 Name:Jane     
         4 Name:Jones
```

This will give you the difference between any attributes in the string, name, age, gender etc. which doesn't match with other string.